# Accessing JSON data from JavaScript on a web page

Tags: javascript, json, web

I have a moderately large JSON data file and I want to access it from the JavaScript code on my web page. What is the simplest way to do that? Should this be done on the client side, or is it better to do that on server side?

Comment: It depends on the situation: how large is the JSON file?

Comment: About 100000 small objects (each containing from 5 to 10 integer values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done on the client side. Use server to read and print content on page in needed for javascript format. If you want save it you also need to send content to server.

Comment: No, it's possible to store JSON objects on the client-side using Lawnchair and other libraries: http://brian.io/lawnchair/

Comment: you mean if you do that on one local computer?